# free() : no double free detected

Tags: c, free, glibc

I have some problems with `free()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char *a=malloc(24);
    char *b=malloc(24);
    free(a);
    free(a);
}
```

there is a "*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption".
That's not surprising because i used `free()` twice.

But now if i do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char *a=malloc(24);
    char *b=malloc(24);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(a);
}
```

there are no errors from my computer, no double free error message, but as you can see there is double free in my code...

Do you know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer why the double free doesn't happen to be detected in your second example other than to guess that libc's primary objective is to be performant by default. So checking for things like double-free probably isn't something the library puts much effort into detecting by default.

However if you run the program with the `MALLOC_CHECK_` environment variable set to 1 you do get a diagnostic on `stderr` (set the variable to 2 for an abort, 3 for an abort with the diagnostic and crashdump info written to `stderr`):

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ ./test
$ MALLOC_CHECK_=1 ./test
*** glibc detected *** ./test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000015e4010 ***
```

(Note the trailing underscore on the environment variable name).

The behavior of libc's heap checking configured with `MALLOC_CHECK_` is documented on the ["Heap Consistency Checking" page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html):

> Another possibility to check for and guard against bugs in the use of
>   malloc, realloc and free is to set the environment variable
>   MALLOC_CHECK_. When MALLOC_CHECK_ is set, a special (less efficient)
>   implementation is used which is designed to be tolerant against simple
>   errors, such as double calls of free with the same argument, or
>   overruns of a single byte (off-by-one bugs). Not all such errors can
>   be protected against, however, and memory leaks can result. If
>   MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to 0, any detected heap corruption is silently
>   ignored; if set to 1, a diagnostic is printed on stderr; if set to 2,
>   abort is called immediately. This can be useful because otherwise a
>   crash may happen much later, and the true cause for the problem is
>   then very hard to track down.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you should have an understanding of glibc malloc mechanism. If you know nothing about it, you can read [this](https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/understanding-glibc-malloc/) to have a general knowledge to glibc malloc.

Glibc uses **bins** to manage chunks you freed for avoiding frequently system calling. Because of the fact that small memory spaces are allocated and freed more frequently, glibc uses **fast bins** (equidistant single linked lists) to manage memory spaces which are less than **global_max_fast** (default 64B or 128B). What the glibc does is to set the **fd** of the chunk you freed to point to where a fast bin points, and let the fast bin point to that chunk.

free() uses the **PREV_INUSE** bit of the next neighboring chunk to check if a chunk is freed. However, when a chunk you freed is added to fast bins, glibc doesn't set the **PREV_INUSE** bit. There is a piece of code to check if the pointer of a fast bin is the same as the pointer of chunk you freed.If it is, the program corrupts, so you can't free a pointer twice, but you can free two pointers in turn.Here is a brief diagram to help you understand.

When you free(a):

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+  16  +  24  +  32  +  ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++
          |
          |
          |
          |
          +--->+--------+
               |prevsize|
               +--------+
               |  size  |
               +--------+
               |fd=NULL |
               +--------+
               |  ...   |
               +--------+
```

When you free(b):

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+  16  +  24  +  32  +  ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |    +--------+<---------+
          |    |prevsize|          |
          |    +--------+          |
          |    |  size  |          |
          |    +--------+          |
          |    |fd=NULL |          |
          |    +--------+          |
          |    |  ...   |          |
          +--->+--------+          |
               |prevsize|          |
               +--------+          |
               |  size  |          |
               +--------+          |
               |   fd   |----------+
               +--------+
               |  ...   |
               +--------+
```

When you free(a) again:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+  16  +  24  +  32  +  ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++
          |
          |
          |
          |
          +--->+--------+<---------+
               |prevsize|          |
               +--------+          |
               |  size  |          |
               +--------+          |
               |   fd   |---+      |
               +--------+   |      |
               |  ...   |   |      |
               +--------+<--+      |
               |prevsize|          |
               +--------+          |
               |  size  |          |
               +--------+          |
               |   fd   |----------+
               +--------+
               |  ...   |
               +--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Valgrind to detect double free or corruption. Check out the blog on using valgrind [Link](http://debuggingdoublefreecorruption.blogspot.com.au/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my code, in a functional test where I was *trying* to generate a double-free libc exception, to test logging functionality.

It turns out, gcc had optimized away the `malloc()` call and both `free()` calls when built for Release (-O3 I think).

I tried using `volatile` on `a` to fix that issue, but gcc won't pass `volatile void*` to `free`. Then I tried assigning `a` to a `volatile void* aa`, but gcc still optimized `a` and `aa` away.  I finally got it to work by inserting a `std::cout` message.

```
char* a = malloc(24);
std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
free(a);
free(a);
```

Now the code correctly "crashes" as I want it to, and prints out the desired double-free message and stack dump.